# Parsing an Itunes Podcast Feed with Python/Django

Tags: python, django, parsing, feed, podcast

What is the easiest way if I want to parse an iTunes podcast feed in Python / Django?

http://www.apple.com/itunes/podcasts/specs.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use python feedparser for this(http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/) and its easy to use

```
>>> import feedparser
>>> d = feedparser.parse('http://feedparser.org/docs/examples/atom10.xml')
>>> d['feed']['title']
u'Sample Feed'
```

http://pythonhosted.org/feedparser/introduction.html